# Use previous value until FutureBuilder is completed with next value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future builder and a timer who updates data in certain interval but I want to show progress bar only on first time and when timer triggered new future called this time I don't want to show progress bar but just error (if occurred) and content inside future builder with new data.

Here is what I tried but not worked :

1. I used await in timer and then called setUpdate with completed future it throws error.

Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

2. I used await and assign to new variable in timer and then set future variable with Future.value(completedfuture) and then setUpdate with completed future and it never finishes.

here is my code

```
late Future<dynamic> futData;
futData = pcd(); // then I called this inside onInit method this is where progress should show.


// Try 1  Error : Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'
// Timer Start 
void apiCallerHook() async {
  futData = await loadIntradayDataLoad();
  update();
}

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (e) => apiCallerHook());
// Timer Ends


// Try 2  Error : Future never completes
// Timer Start 
void apiCallerHook() async {
  dynamic proxyFut = await loadIntradayDataLoad();
  futData = Future.value(proxyFut);
  update();
}

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (e) => apiCallerHook());
// Timer Ends
```

Is there a better approach kindly help.

Comment: use `StreamBuilder` and `Stream` api (`Stream.periodic` for example) when you have multiple async values to handle, more here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams